# Synchronized(MyClass.class){ } in Singleton Design Pattern - What does it do?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, syntax, synchronized

I'm learning design patterns and have intermediate experience in Java. I'm attempting to implement the Singleton design pattern and have come across the following code in a method:

```
    public static Singleton getInstance(){

    if( firstInstance == null ){
        if (firstThread){
            firstThread = false;
            Thread.currentThread();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Singleton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        synchronized(Singleton.class){

            if(firstInstance == null){
                firstInstance = new Singleton();
            }

        }


    }

    return firstInstance;
}
```

I understand how the method works, but I have a question with one specific part of this code:

```
        synchronized(Singleton.class){

            if(firstInstance == null){
                firstInstance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
```

I know that the synchronized block forces only this part of the code to be synchronized which makes the implementation thread-safe and doesn't slow down the whole method, but why are we wrapping *`Singleton.class`* in parenthesis before the access modifier *`synchronized`*?

My question is more Java-related than it is Design Pattern-related. I tried searching Google and StackOverflow, but I'm not sure what this is actually called which limits my results.

I hope you guys can help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is called [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java).

Comment: Google'd double-checked locking. Does that mean that the only synchronized code can be locked or can I apply the same idea to other access modifiers? As in: private(this){ /* private code here */ } 
Would that block of code be treated as private within a method?

Comment: No, `synchronized` is a keyword which in a nutshell prevents multiple threads from running the same block concurrently. In double-checked locking it's there to ensure that the singleton instance is only created once. It's double-checked because a short time after the instance is created, threads will begin to see the instance at the first null check and never have to enter the `synchronized` block. I recommend the tutorials if you want to learn about this stuff. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: @holasoyeddy I also added the explanation for access vs non-access modifiers into my answer. See that for a bit more detail.

Comment: Where did you run across this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the normal thing to synchronize on in Java is `this` (e.g. the current instance). But this method is `static`, so there is no instance, just a class. Thus we synchronize on that.

The reason for `synchronizing` this part of the method is so two instances aren't created by two threads at once. This could happen if both do the `firstInstance == null` check at the same time, and upon both finding it is `true`, both decide to create a new instance. This gives us two instances of a `Singleton` class, which is obviously very bad.

Also I think you are confused as you call `synchronized` an [access modifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm).

The only access modifiers are `private`, `public`, and `protected` (plus the hidden default one).

`Synchronized` is a [non-access modifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_nonaccess_modifiers.htm). A single method can have both access and non-access modifiers such as `public static` or `private synchronized`.

Note that only `synchronized` and `static` can have blocks. However, this is more because of what they are used for rather than their modifier classification.

Answer (score 1):

The firstInstance variable is likely a static variable in the Singleton class, containing the only object of that class.

Synchronizing on the class ensures that two different threads don't both try to create the firstInstance object at the same time.  That ensures that the firstInstance variable is only initialized once.

Comment: So, does that mean I would be able to repeat this with other access modifiers, as in:

    private(MyClass.class){
        /* My code here */
     }

Would this make only that code block be treated as a private method?

Comment: @holasoyeddy `synchronized` is a special keyword that operates on an `Object` (the lock). `private` does not operate on anything as it doesn't need a lock. You also cannot have `private` blocks, only `static` and `synchronized`.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks, guys! :)

Comment: @holasoyeddy I think you are confused, synchronized is **not** an [access modifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm) like `private`, `public`, or `protected`. It is a [**non-access modifier**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_nonaccess_modifiers.htm).
A single method can have both access and non-access modifiers such as `public static` or `private synchronized`

Comment: I was not aware of this. Sorry for not being informed. School is teaching me the basics, but things like these are a bit more self-taught. I must not have covered that when learning Java. Thank you!